# modx ошибка 500 при открытии сайта

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, modx, revo

Всех приветствую, при открытии сайта появляется белый экран и ошибка HTTP ERROR 500. При этом админ панель открывается нормально. Используется MODX Revolution 2.2.4-pl (traditional). В логах такие ошибки, в чем проблема и как исправить не имею понятия:

```
[2020-11-23 15:35:48] (ERROR @ /connectors/resource/index.php) xPDO->removeObject - Error deleting modDbRegisterMessage instance using query 
[2020-11-23 15:36:31] (ERROR @ /manager/index.php) xPDO->removeObject - Error deleting modDbRegisterMessage instance using query
```

Comment: какая-то таблица в базе сломалась

Answer (score 0):

Похоже проблема с https://docs.modx.org/current/ru/extending-modx/services/modregistry
Если админка работает полноценно, попробуйте обновить поверх той же или более свежей версией.
Кстати, ваша версия катастрофически старая! Нужно последовательно обновить до актуальной, после этих шагов ситуация должна исправится(если не хватает прав, при обновлении установщик обычно подсказывает)
2.2.4 -> 2.3 - >2.4 -> 2.5 -> 2.6 -> 2.7 -> 2.8.1

Comment: да, зная что очень старая версия. Проблема в том что старые версии modx, не скачиваются на офф сайте. И поэтому не могу ни переустановить эту версию ни обновить последовательно на 2.3 и т.д